# How to copy large folders in windows without getting stuck all the time?

Tags: windows, windows-10

How can I copy large folders in windows 10 from external drive to partition without getting stuck all the time? In the end I always have to reboot windows, and to copy subfolders by hand to evade these problems. Is there a tool that actually works?

Comment: The usual copy does not seems to work as it has a bug. It cannot handle symlinks. Still not fixed?

Comment: I don't care if the file is 1 MB or 1 TB. The process of copying the file shouldn't become "stuck".  It sounds like the destination disk might have an I/O problem. I have copied files that are much larger than 1 TB without a problem.  It might take awhile but in my experience the file transfer process has never become "stuck".

Comment: It is because of symlinks. At a symlink the process stops. Thats it.

Comment: Your question makes no mention of the use of a symlink.

Comment: Use [`RoboCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy): `RoboCopy "C:\Path\to\Source" "Z:\Path\to\Destination" /e /z  /sj /sl /v /eta /log+:"C:\RoboCopy.log"` _(if destination is a network share, add: `/tbd`)_. **`/sj`:** copy Junctions as junctions instead of as the junction targets | **`/sl`:** copy Symbolic Links as links instead of as the link targets. _(I'll create an answer for this tomorrow, as I don't have time at the moment)_

Comment: Please add more information, including that regarding symlinks being the things the transfer is stopping on, how you are doing these copies, and any other relevant information. At this time your question lacks the information necessary to understand your problem fully enough to answer it.

Comment: Well, when the copying encounters a symlink it stops. Not sure what else to say on that point. But a workaround is: Copy the files using Linux. Then it works fine